# DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters) parameter with value 0 sent as "default" to the database

Tags: entity-framework

I have a code like this:

```
const string query = "select count(*) from query with parameters"
     + "@param1, @param2..."
```

(Obvioulsy is pseudocode). When I run the query like this:

```
ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>(query,
   new SqlParameter("param1", idAsociacion),
   new SqlParameter("param2", 0));
```

I get an exception stating that I didn't provide a value for param2.

If I use SQl Server Profiles I see that the generated query looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'The query', @param1=N'P', @param2=default
```

If I try to run it directly in SQL Server I do also get the error that param2 is required and not provided (I don't know the exact error in English, because I have a localized SQL Server).

Why is EF converting the value `0` into `default`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was a silly one.

When I put the mouse pointer over this constructor invocation in VS:

```
new SqlParameter("param2", 0)
```

I see that the `SqlParameter` overload being invoked is not this one:

```
SqlParameter(string, object)
```

but this one

```
SqlParameter(string, SqlDbType)
```

So, the simple solution is to invoke the constructor casting the value to object, like this:

```
new SqlParameter("param2", (object)0)
```

so the correct overload is invoked, and it works as expected.